# Convergence of series of dependent random variable, central limit theorem

Tags: probability, convergence, central-limit-theorem

My friend and I have a problem on central limit theorem.

Given $X_1,X_2......$ are i.i.d random variables with mean $\mu$=0,  variance $\sigma^2=1$(may or may not be normally distributed). If we define: $Y_n=X_1X_2+X_2X_3+....X_{n-1}X_n$, how to show the  $\frac{Y_n}{n}\to N(0,1)$ when $n\to\infty$. i.e.
$$\frac{X_1X_2+X_2X_3+....X_{n-1}X_n}{n}\to N(0,1),as \ n\to \infty$$

I am not sure denominator is n or n-1. It is obvious that $X_1X_2$ and $X_2X_3 $ are dependent, so I cannot use the standard central limit theorem. I also find the $\textit{Lindeberg-Feller CLT}$, but it is used on Independent but not identically distributed random variables.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: The choice of n vs n-1 makes no difference in the limit.

Comment: There are versions of the central limit theorem that apply to weakly dependent random variables. Maybe you can find one that applies in your case. A good source is the collected works of Wassily Hoeffding published by Springer-Verlag which has the paper by Hoeffding and Robbins on pages 205-213, titled "The Central Limit Theorem for Dependent Random Variables".

Comment: Thx, I will find that good source.

Comment: It doesn't converge to $N(0,1)$, actually; the variance will be not far from $1/n$, I suspect.